# Search and view Elasticsearch results from an HTML

Tags: html, elasticsearch, kibana

I am currently working on a project and as the title suggests, what I want to do is to be able to search from an HTML a cluster already uploaded on elasticsearch and preview the results back in the HTML.

I thought of using Logstash to send the search input from HTML to elasticsearch but I can't figure a way of viewing those results back in the HTML. In general what I want to do, is to be able to work with elasticsearch the way kibana does, but from a website.

Appreciate any possible help :)

Answer (score 1):

use php-elastic official library(https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php).

You can use the following code to get the search result:

```
$this->client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(["ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:ELASTICSEARCH_PORT"])->build();

$queryBody = ["match_all" => new \stdClass()];

if($search) {
$queryBody = [
    "match" => [
        "_all" => $search
    ]
];
```

}

```
$params = [
"from" => $page * $this->pageSize, // if you want data for pagination  
"size" => $this->pageSize, // if you want data for pagination               
"index" => $index,
"type" => $type,
"_source_include" => $fields, // Your required field array
"body" => [
    "query" => $queryBody
]
```

];

```
//Get the search result
$response = $this->client->search($params);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will have to try it later because I have some issues to resolve first.

Comment: Hey Adi, I tried your approach with a few changes. Bottom line, it works! How can I now preview the results in a more user friendly way, like every search engine does?

Comment: Hey Savvas, if you can use laravel, then I have created a plugin for Elasticsearch view in laravel. You can use that. Link of plugin https://github.com/adityawritso/Successive-Laravel-Elasticsearch-View

Comment: Thank you again Adi! I will give it a shot :)